# How can I get proper axios.post data, not html-format code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, next.js

After axios.post, response.data only return html code and what I sent is in response.config.data.
Moreover, in the server side, console.log is not working but in vscode console, it returns
POST /tagSearch 200 95.325 ms - -

I'm using express and nextjs. Plz help me.....

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGGOY.png)

Here's my code.

client side, pages/tagSearch.js

```
const onClick = () => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3060/tagSearch', {
      "id": 7,
      "name": 'mango'
    },
      {
        headers: { "Content-Type": `application/json` }
      }
    )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      }
      )
  }
```

server side, app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var tagSearchRouter = require('./routes/tagSearch');

app.use('/tagSearch', tagSearchRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

server side, routes/tagSearch.js

```
router.post('/', (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body);
})
```

Comment: Looks like some other bit of code is responding to the request and it never reaches your route (which lacks a body parser and any code to send a response).

Comment: @Quentin
Actually, in server side, there's code like `app.use(express.json()); `
Isn't it body-parser..?